# Changing margins based on window width

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the margins dynamically based on the windows width?

For example:
`margin: 100px 200px 50px;` when the window is at full size and when you resize the window it starts lessening the margins by increments of 10, for example.

Now I'm using @media, which works but doesn't look really it. The margins basically snap when the width is 1500px.

Comment: Youcould use the `vw` unit for that.

Comment: Use margin: 7vw 13vw 4vw 0;.

Comment: Sorry if my questions seem a bit stupid, I'm new to this. So, what would margin: 7vw 13vw 4vw 0; do exactly? And wouldn't this result in my wrapper not being centered anymore?